# Folder Encryption and Debugging in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, debugging, directory, encryption

This may be a simple question but I will throw it out anyway.

My company's standard is to encrypt the contents of specific folders on our laptops, so in the case our laptops are stolen, the thieves would have a more difficult time at getting to "sensitive" information.

We are now being asked to encrypt our code that we work on (ASP.NET, winforms, WPF, etc.) for the same reason. Prior to this, our code lives in an unencrypted folder and everything works fine when we try to debug.

I tried to encrypt the folder for one of my projects, built it and started debugging. Note that this is a ASP.NET Web App running on Windows 7. I get the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

---

Access is denied. 
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the requested resources.

Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'c:\dev\rdsims\development\Web\HomePage.aspx'.

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

Has anyone else encountered this? Do you need more information?

Comment: How are folders being encrypted? Bitlocker, custom program, etc ...

Comment: Whatever comes standard with Windows 7

Comment: Do you still get this if you run Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: Yes the only time I don't get the error is if the folders/files are unencrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer... By default, it should work. Debugging a vanilla asp.net application on my laptop should be fine because it is running in the context of me, and I have the keys to the kingdom when it comes to encryption/decryption. HOWEVER, the application I am trying to debug runs impersonated as a different user (and thus does not have the proper access). So, the solution is going to be to debug on my laptop not impersonating the user, and then when it migrates out to QA and production, make sure the code is in place to impersonate, etc